# Pydantic V2 patching model fields

Tags: python, pydantic

## Problem

I'm attempting to patch one or more fields of a pydantic model (v2+) in a unit test.

#### Why?

I want to mock some enum field, with a simpler/smaller enum to reduce the test assertion noise. For example, if I have;

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Foo(BaseModel):
    field: FooEnum
```

where `FooEnum` is

```py
from enum import Enum

class FooEnum(Enum):
    """Some enum with lot's of fields"""
```

If I want to explicitly validate the behaviour when some invalid enum is passed to `Foo`, the error message can be a nuisance to deal with. As such, I wanted to mock `Foo.field` with some smaller `MockFooEnum`, to improve testing readability/remove the need to update this unit test when a new field is added to `FooEnum`.

## Attempted solutions

The following approach "works", but this was the result of hacking around in pydantic source code, to see how I could patch fields.

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager
from unittest import mock
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from pydantic import BaseModel
    from pydantic.fields import FieldInfo


@contextmanager
def patch_pydantic_model_field(
    target: type[BaseModel], field_overrides: dict[str, FieldInfo]
) -> Generator[type[BaseModel], None, None]:
    model_fields = target.model_fields

    with mock.patch.object(
        target=target, attribute="model_fields", new_callable=mock.PropertyMock
    ) as mock_fields:
        # ? Override the model with new mocked fields.
        mock_fields.return_value = model_fields | field_overrides
        target.model_rebuild(force=True)

        yield target

    target.model_rebuild(force=True)
```

#### Usage

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "field_overrides",
    [{"field": FieldInfo(annotation=MockFooEnum, required=True)}],
)
def test_foo(field_overrides):
    with patch_pydantic_model_field(Foo, field_overrides):
        assert <something_with_mocked_model>
```

This approach seems a bit of a bodge and was curious if there is a nicer way to achieve the above.

Comment: I've had similar challenges with mocking / patching enums in pydantic fields. Unfortunately, I think your provided solution is going to be the best you can get (for now). Consider opening a feature request! https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/discussions/categories/feature-request

Answer (score 1):

I do not think using a mock value is a good idea. For testing you usually want to test as much of the actual code as possible.

If you know exactly what you are doing, you could alternative create a new modified model using the `create_model` function:

```
from enum import Enum
from pydantic import BaseModel, create_model

class FooEnumLarge(Enum):
    """Some enum with lot's of fields"""
    one = 1
    two = 2
    three = 3
    four = 4
    five = 5


class FooEnumSmall(Enum):
    """Some enum with fewer fields"""
    one = 1
    two = 2


class Foo(BaseModel):
    field: FooEnumLarge


FooTest = create_model("FooNew", __base__=Foo, field=(FooEnumSmall, ...))

print(Foo(field=1))
print(FooTest(field=1))
```

Which prints:

```
field=<FooEnumLarge.one: 1>
field=<FooEnumSmall.one: 1>
```

So you could write a context manager, that does not modify the existing, but returns a new class:

```
with context_overide_fields(Foo, ...) as FooNew:
    FooNew()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The reason I opted for patching the field, is that the new model will need to be patched anyway, so the end result is the same.

The reason for patching, is that the Enum in question is a library enum. Therefore changes to this enum, shoudn't result in failures to my consumer test (as much as possible). Patching in this context is mitigating (not eliminating) this risk